# What difference between "you're working hard today" and "you've worked hard today"?

Tags: grammar

What difference between "you're working hard today" and "you've worked hard today"? I think these sentences have the same meaning, but I'm not sure.

Comment: They are different tenses and have different meanings. Please check up "present continuous" and "present perfect".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You are working hard today --> you're still doing the work.

Example: You are a boss in an office and you're finding one of your staff exhausted while he/she is STILL WORKING. Then you say *"You can take some rest, you're working hard today."*

> You have worked hard today. --> you have finished the work.

Example: You are a boss in an office and accidentally meet one of your staff in a restaurant while you're having dinner. You may say *"Hello John, thanks for you papers. You have worked hard today."*

Comment: +1 But you need *one of your staff*, not *one of your staff**S***! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Unless of course it is a magical office and the boss, a wizard, is addressing a sentient staff, one of many--in which case it should be *one of your staves*.

Comment: @StoneyB I can't even. You're the best, don't ever change :)

Answer (score 2):

> working

current, ongoing, we are speaking during the day

> worked

past, said at the end of the day.

Comment: I wouldn't say "you've worked hard today" is "past".

Comment: It would be said in the context of looking back over the day. So informally it is surely referring to the past, albeit the recent past, in contrast to the "working" case where the work is currently happening. I thought that technically, "have worked" is the Past Perfect, is that not the case?

Comment: "have worked" is not past perfect tense and this is one of the reasons why I have downvoted your answer.

Comment: Ah, I think you are saying it's the Present Perfect, is that correct? The reference I found says this: "This tense indicates either that an action was completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the past or that the action extends to the present". So, I'm still thinking that we are talking about some action (work) that completed today. Is it incorrect to say that we are taking about the past?

Comment: Yes, it is the "present perfect" tense and yes it does refer to an event in the past. Had you written that in your answer, it would have been acceptable in my eyes. Hopefully now you realize why I couldn't endorse your original answer.

Comment: Leo, thank you. Over the years I have found that a beneficial side-effect of answering questions is that I learn a great deal; it's always good to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your earnest responses. I would do well to learn from your unpretentious attitude.